# How to post an image to azure-blob-storage from front-end(Angular8) while passing the file to backend(C#)

Tags: asp.net, api, frontend, angular8, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to allow users to upload an image for their profile pic. I want to store it inside of my azure-blob-storage. So after doing some research and going through different theories about doing this solely within the front end, I have decided to just pass the file to the backend and make the backend post to my azure blob. However, upon doing so, I get a 500 Internal Server error while attempting to upload a selected file.

I am using Angular 8 for my frontend code and using C#/ASP.NetCore for my backend. I have been able to successfully post an image to my azure-blob-storage with just my backend by using PostMan to see if my controller works. The main issue is getting my frontend code to pass this file to my controller which will handle posting to the azure-blob-storage.

I am using a service to provide a linkage between my upload-picture-component and the backend controller.

FrontEnd(Angular8)
'upload-profile-service.ts' snippet:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpEvent, HttpParams, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '@env/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UploadProfileImageService {

  // dependency injection
  constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  private baseurl =  environment.api + '/myupload';

  // change from any to type image.
  public getImages(): Observable<any> {
    return this._httpClient.get(this.baseurl);
  }

  // Form Data as image to pass to API to be pushed to Azure Storage
  public postImages(formData: FormData): Observable<any> {
    const saveImageUrl = this.baseurl + '/SaveFile';
    return this._httpClient.post<any>(saveImageUrl, formData);
  }
```

'upload-profile-component.ts' snippet:

```
  constructor(
    private consultantStore: ConsultantStore,
    private notification: NotificationsService,
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<Upload-Picture-Component>,
    private _uploadProfileImageService: UploadProfileImageService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(){}

selectedFile: File = null;
imageChangedEvent: any = '';

  fileChangeEvent(event: any): void {
    this.imageChangedEvent = event;
    this.selectedFile = <File>this.imageChangedEvent.target.files[0];
  }

  UploadImageToBlob(){
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(this.selectedFile.name, this.selctedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
    this._uploadProfileImageService.postImages(formData)
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
      })

  }
```

BackEnd(C#)
'UploadPicController.cs' snippet

```
    [Route("myupload")]
    [ApiController]
    public class FileUploadController : Controller
    {
        private string _conn = <my_key_to_azure_blob_storage>;
        private CloudBlobClient _blobClient;
        private CloudBlobContainer _container;
        private CloudStorageAccount _storageAccount;
        private CloudBlockBlob _blockBlob;

 [HttpPost("[Action]")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SaveFile(IFormFile files)
        {

            _storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_conn);
            _blobClient = _storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            _container = _blobClient.GetContainerReference("profileimages");
            //Get a reference to a blob
            _blockBlob = _container.GetBlockBlobReference(files.FileName);

            //Create or overwrite the blob with contents of a local file
            using (var fileStream = files.OpenReadStream())
            {
                await _blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);

            }
            return Json(new
            {
                name = _blockBlob.Name,
                uri = _blockBlob.Uri,
                size = _blockBlob.Properties.Length
            });
        }
}
```

I want my azure blob to be able to receive the image via httpPost when the UploadImageToBlob function is called, but instead, I receive this error...

> zone.js:3372 POST http://localhost:5000/myupload/SaveFile 500 (Internal Server Error)...
>
> core.js:5847 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error", url: "http://localhost:5000/myupload/SaveFile", ok: false, …}error: "
>   ↵http://localhost:5000/myupload/SaveFile: 500 Internal Server Error"name: "HttpErrorResponse"ok: falsestatus: 500statusText: "Internal Server Error"url: "http://localhost:5000/myupload/SaveFile"**proto**: HttpResponseBase...

Here is an **update** on what I get in the error log in Developer Tools
'NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
[Developer Tools -> 'Preview'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXLQp.png)

Comment: Put a try..catch around the code in your SaveFile method, stick a breakpoint on it and have a look at the actual exception being thrown

Comment: I get this 'NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' when it tries to set the blob to my container reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my HttpPost method which worked for me:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFileAsync([FromForm]IFormFile file)
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = null;
            if (CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(_configuration.GetConnectionString("StorageAccount"), out storageAccount))
            {
                var client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                var container = client.GetContainerReference("fileupload");
                await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
                CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(file.FileName);
                await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(file.OpenReadStream());
                return Ok(blob.Uri);
            }

            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
        }
```

I was also getting the same issue when i tried to use below method:

```
GetBlockBlobReference() or `GetBlobReferenceFromServerAsync`
```

Also i would suggest you to add below line after getting the container reference:

await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

When I debugged the code in network tab in developer tools while i was using GetBlobReferenceFromServerAsync()

here is the reason which was causing 500:

[image]

Please try to debug it from your end and see if it helps.

Let me know if you any assistance, will share my code base.

Comment: I get a 'NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error. And it highlights the 'CloudBlockBlob blob = _container.GetBlockBlobReference(file.FileName);' Any idea why? You said that this does work for your app right? Also, thanks for the comment!

Comment: Ok instead of using file.FileName, I just made a dummy string and now I get the exact error you are. Were you able to fix it when it said 'specified blob does not exist'?

Comment: It seems that the file that is being passed from my front end is "Null". So for that reason, it can't find the (file.FileName), which is why I may be getting that ' NullReferenceException'...

Comment: Let me share one sample repo , you can refer that for reference.

Comment: For sure! Do you remember how you solved that error? I am still stuck as the file that gets passed towards the backend is null.

Comment: you can refer the front end angular code Also debug your angular code to see whether it is posting the file or not.

Comment: So it seems that the file isn’t appending to my FormData. When I debugged, I noticed that on the front end, the formData is completely empty as if the file never was there.